# A result related to Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

I am studying the prime number theorem and related stuff and was trying to solve this following problem:

Suppose there exists a constant $c$ such that $\psi(x) = x + (c + o(1))\frac{x}{\log x}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Deduce that $\int_2^x \frac{\psi(t)}{t^2} dt = \log x + (c + o(1))\log\log x$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

I can understand that I have to split the interval of integral from $2$ to $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt x$ to $x$, and probably use the given relation in the second integral, but I am kind of getting all stuck. And also, a bit lost on the first integral.
Any hints or explanations/suggestions please?
Thanks

Comment: No you don't need to split the integral. Plugging in the asymptotic for $\psi(t)$ into the interval is sufficient.

Comment: Is it okay to split it like this? $$\int_2^{\log\log X}\dfrac{\psi(t)}{t^2}dt+\int_{\log\log X}^{X},$$
and use $\psi(t)=O(t)$ in the first one.